# Intel (Skylake) UnCore

Tags: linux

I am trying to understand the linux kernel code regarding the uncore performance counters for Skylake hardware. The code at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/arch/x86/events/intel/uncore_snbep.c#L3565 magically uses the constant 0x208d.

Where can I find the meaning of this constant and does it represent?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The constant is used in a `pci_get_device()` function call; by clicking the function name you can instantly jump to its [definition](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/drivers/pci/search.c#L331) in drivers/pci/search.c. The code looks like this:

```
/**
 * pci_get_device - begin or continue searching for a PCI device by vendor/device id
 * @vendor: PCI vendor id to match, or %PCI_ANY_ID to match all vendor ids
 * @device: PCI device id to match, or %PCI_ANY_ID to match all device ids
 * ...
 */
struct pci_dev *pci_get_device(unsigned int vendor, unsigned int device,
                   struct pci_dev *from)
{
    ...
}
```

So it should be obvious that the meaning of the parameter is a PCI "device ID".

**What's a device ID, then?**

All PCI devices have a 16-bit "vendor ID" and a 16-bit "device ID" or "model ID", which are reported during PCI scan (see `lspci -tvnn`). The (vendor, device) pair is used to determine the correct driver for the device.

So PCI_VENDOR_ID_INTEL is a macro for Intel's vendor ID (which is of course 0x8086, assigned by PCI-SIG), and the next parameter 0x208d indicates a specific device type (as assigned by Intel themselves).

The [PCI ID Repository](https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/8086/208d) describes the device 8086:208d as "Sky Lake-E CHA Registers" (you'll likely see a similar name in lspci), so it's probably just a virtual device that's part of the Skylake uncore.

Comment: Thanks! But i still don't get it: Why the kernel 5.2 kernel is using another constant https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2-rc1/source/arch/x86/events/intel/uncore_snbep.c#L3698 ?

Comment: See [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/linus/320b0651f32b830add6497fcdcfdcb6ae8c7b8a0). Use `git log` and `tig blame` to find out why a change was made.

Comment: OK; maybe i have to dig more; 2083 is the PCU registers (power control). Currently i don't see why that one should look at those registers first in order to enumerate the CHA registers.

Comment: If it looks particularly odd, check the LKML mailing list – it might have threads where that patch was reviewed in case they discuss this change. Or you could email the author.